# How can I optimize my MongoDB Upsert statement?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

A decision was made to switch our database from SQL to noSQL and I have a few questions on best practices and if my current implementation could be improved.

My current SQL implementation for upserting player data after a game.

```
   let template = Players.map(
      (player) =>
        `(
          ${player.Rank},"${player.Player_ID}","${player.Player}",${player.Score},${tpp},1
         )`,
       ).join(',');

    let stmt = `INSERT INTO playerStats (Rank, Player_ID, Player, Score, TPP, Games_Played) 
                VALUES ${template}
                ON CONFLICT(Player_ID) DO UPDATE 
                SET Score = Score+excluded.Score,
                            Games_Played=Games_Played+1,
                            TPP=TPP+excluded.TPP`;

    db.run(stmt, function (upsert_error) { ...
```

The expected code is to update existing players by checking if a current `Player_id` exist. If so update their score among other things. Else insert a new player.

Mongo Implementation

```
const players = [
        { name: 'George', score: 10, id: 'g65873' },
        { name: 'Wayne', score: 100, id: 'g63853' },
        { name: 'Jhonny', score: 500, id: 'b1234' },
        { name: 'David', score: 3, id: 'a5678' },
        { name: 'Dallas', score: 333333, id: 'a98234' },
      ];
const db = client.db(dbName);
const results = players.map((player) => {

    // updateOne(query, update, options)
    db.collection('Players')
      .updateOne(
         { Player_Name: player.name },
         {
           $setOnInsert: { Player_Name: player.name, id: player.id },
           $inc: { Score: player.score },
         },
         { upsert: true, multi: true },
       );
    });
```

Is there a better way in mongo to implement this? I tried using updateMany and bulkUpdate and I didn't get the results I expected.

Are there any tips, tricks, or resources aside from the mongo.db that you would recommend for those moving from SQL to noSQL?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. However, there are a few flaws:

- Command `updateOne` updates exactly one document as the name implies. Thus `multi: true`
  is obsolete.
- Field names are case-sensitive (unlike most SQL databases). It should be `$inc: { score: player.score }`, not "**S**core"
- Field `Player_Name` does not exist, it will never find any document for update.

So, your command should be like this:

```
db.collection('Players').updateOne(
   { name: player.name }, //or { id: player.id } ?
   {
      $setOnInsert: { name: player.name, id: player.id },
      $inc: { score: player.score },
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

According to my experience, moving from SQL to NoSQL is harder if you try to translate the SQL statement you have in your mind into a NoSQL command one-by-one. For me it worked better when I wiped out the SQL idea and try to understand and develop the NoSQL command from scratch.

Of course, when you do your first `find`, `delete`, `insert`, `update` then you will see many analogies to SQL but latest when you approach to the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) you are lost if you try to translate them into SQL or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps me!